# After creating new position in database, redirect directly to the newly created view

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes

AT my website you can create collaborators. I have a blade view with a table where you can see all of them. I want after creating new collaborator to return the main view of newly created collaborator.

I was thinking that I can either add it in my javascript function or maybe in route function instead of `return back` use like `return view('person.profile.profile-view');` but I don't know how to pass all the data I need from a newly created field.

Also, my collaborator view needs a lot of data, here is the controller for it:

```php
 public function profileView($id)
    {
        $person = $this->personRepository->getByIdWith($id, ['person_title', 'country', 'salutation']);
        $practitioner_id = $this->practitionerRepository->getIdByPersonId($id);
        $practitioner = $this->practitionerRepository->getById($practitioner_id);
        $specialty_id = PractitionerSpecialty::where('practitioner_id', $practitioner_id)->value('specialty_id');

        return view('person.profile.profile-view')
            ->with('person', $person)
            ->with('id', $id)
            ->with('person_titles', $this->personTitleRepository->getAll())
            ->with('countries', Country::all())
            ->with('specialties', Specialty::all())
            ->with('specialty', Specialty::where('specialty_id', $specialty_id)->value('name'))
            ->with('competence_levels', CompetenceLevel::all())
            ->with('salutations', PersonSalutation::all())
            ->with('practitioner', $practitioner)
            ->with('practitioner_specialty', PractitionerSpecialty::where('practitioner_id', $practitioner_id)->first())
            ->with('practitioner_competence_level', PractitionerCompetenceLevel::where('practitioner_id', $practitioner_id)->first());
    }
```

My php create form

```
<div class="modal fade crud-modal" id="create-Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1050; display: none;"
     aria-hidden="true">

               [...]                     

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round waves-effect "
                        data-dismiss="modal">{{trans('buttons.close')}}</button>
                <button type="button" id="create_final_btn" class="btn btn-success btn-round"
                        >{{trans('buttons.add')}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var create = (function(){
    var onSuccess;
    var onHashSuccess;

    var createButton = function(fieldValues, createUrl, required) {
        $("#create_final_btn").click(function () {
            forms.postObject(forms.readForm(fieldValues, '_create', undefined,  required), createUrl, onSuccess);
        });
    };

    [...]

    var setOnSuccess = function(fun) {
      onSuccess = fun;
    };
    var setOnHashSuccess = function(fun) {
        onHashSuccess = fun;
      };

    return {
        createButton: createButton,
        createHashItemButton: createHashItemButton,
        openCreateDialogButton: openCreateDialogButton,
        setOnSuccess: setOnSuccess,
        setOnHashSuccess: setOnHashSuccess,
        openCreateTrainingPlanButton: openCreateTrainingPlanButton
    };
}());
```

My function in routes:

```php
public function addPerson(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'data' => 'required',
                'data.first_name' => 'required',
                'data.last_name' => 'required',
                'data.active' => 'required',
                'data.person_salutation_id' => 'required',

            ]
        );
        $this->repository->create($request->all()['data']);
        return back();
    }
```

I think the best way would be to do that in javascript function. If someone can lead me to the best solution that would be great.

Comment: If you handle POST request with JS, you have to redirect with JS too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
return back();
```

use

```
$object = $this->repository->create($request->all()['data']);

return redirect()->route('routename', ['id' => $object->id]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the redirect, but even after changing it, it still stays on the same site. Right now it also doesn't show the newest record in the table, it appears after I refresh the page.